# How can I create a link that opens a page and shows a hidden div inside?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a page where there is a hidden div. This div is shown within this page on the click of a certain button. Is it possible to create a link (for example to insert in an email) that opens that page and shows that hidden div? Thanks

**EDIT**

Is it possible, at the same time, to show one div and hide others? For example:

```
website.com/page.php#show
```

This link does the job. At the same time can I cause other divs to be hidden?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### CSS Solution

Definitely. With the CSS [:target selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target) you can change the styles of an element based on the hash value in the URL. Check out the example below. It adds `#show` to the URL which makes the hidden div visible. This is because the `#show` hash matches the `id` attribute on the div. That way it knows that it is being targeted.

If you'd add a hash in your link which matches the the `id` attribute value of the div on your page, and add the CSS to your styles, then you'll be able to create this effect.

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.hidden:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#first">Show the first div</a>
<a href="#second">Show the second div</a>
<a href="#third">Show the third div</a>

<div class="hidden" id="first">Excelsior!</div>
<div class="hidden" id="second">Tadaa!</div>
<div class="hidden" id="third">Shazam!</div>
```

---

### Addendum: JavaScript solution

Changing the visibility of unrelated elements will call for the help of JavaScript. With it we can determine that any other div that is not being targeted should be hidden from the document. We'll do that by reading the URL.

The `hash` property of the `location` object will tell us if the hash has a value or not. We can compare the value of the hash to the id of the elements we select to determine if they should be shown or hidden based on the hash.

The example below here selects all elements with `class="js-target"` and checks if the `id` of each element matches the `hash` value. If it does, it shows that element, if not it hides that element. This will result in all **non-matching** elements to be hidden.

```js
// Selects all divs with the .js-target class.
const targets = document.querySelectorAll('div.js-target');

/**
 * Show the target that has an id that matches
 * with the hash value in the URL and hides the
 * ones that don't match.
 */
const toggleTargets = () => {
  const { hash } = window.location;
  if (hash === '') {
    return;
  }
  /**
   * Loop over each target and check if the id matches
   * the hash value. If it does, then remove the hidden 
   * class, if not, add the hidden class.
   */
  targets.forEach(target => {
    if (`#${target.id}` === hash) {
      target.classList.remove('hidden');
    } else {
      target.classList.add('hidden');
    }
  });
}

/**
 * Immediately execute the toggleTargets function when
 * the script is loaded.
 */
toggleTargets();

/**
 * Whenever the hash changes when on the page, call toggleTargets
 * again to re-evaluate if the hash matches any div.
 */
window.addEventListener('hashchange', toggleTargets);
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#tadaa">Show the targeted div</a>

<div class="js-target">Excelsior!</div>
<div class="js-target hidden" id="tadaa">Tadaa!</div>
<div class="js-target">Shazam!</div>
```

Comment: Great, thanks. It works. Please take a look at the edit in the body of the question.

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Style your divs that by default they will be hidden. Then give them unique `id` values to target the specific div that you want to show based on the URL. I've modified the example to show you what that would look like.

Comment: No sorry, maybe I explained myself wrong or I didn't understand. My page consists of 3 divs (#div1, #div2, #show). By default, the first two are visible, the other hidden. When I visit the link we are talking about (website.com/page.php#show) I would like not only #show to be shown but also #div1 and #div2 to be hidden. Is this possible?

Comment: Well, yes that is possible. It would require some JavaScript to do the job. I'll make an addendum to the answer. Just as a bit of feedback. Adding code which is related to the question always helps you to explain your question and makes sure that the solutions we present fit with your presented code.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's perfect. I learned something new.